# Updating a SQL Server Geometry column

Tags: sql-server, geometry, gis

I'm trying to translate points and polygons from a country-specific coordinate system towards a latitude-longitude system (GPS).

Although I have the (rather complex) formula to calculate the translation given a particular set of coordinates, I'm stuck with the SQL Server geometry column, which contains not only points, but also polygons and lines.

The way I tried to fix this:

- find the maximum number of points in the geometry column of a table (using `STNumPoints())`)
- using a `while`-loop and an iterator `@i`, walk through all geometry points (up to the maximum found earlier)
- update all the geometry-instances that have <= `@i` points, translating the `@i`th point towards the GPS coordinate-system

This has but one problem: it seems that SQL Server won't let me update a single point in a Geometry instances.

I tried to find information about updating Geometry instances on the web, but couldn't find any.

Is it possible to update parts of Geometry-instance? If it is, what are the restrictions / preconditions to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the geometry methods, I don't think so. An alternative would be to store them disaggregated (that is, storing your polygons as their constituent points) and then aggregating them when you're ready to treat them as a polygon.

One other note: if this information does in fact represent points on a globe, consider using the geography data type instead. It takes the curvature of the earth into account so things like distance and area are going to be more accurate.

Comment: I want to store the points into a Geography indeed - however, in order to do that, the SRID of the source coordinates must be supported (and the Dutch coordinate system apparently is not, so I have to convert the values). I've worked around it for now, will soon post a blogpost about it :).

Answer (score 0):

you can update like this:

```
SET @sqlCommand = 'USE [' + @databaseName + '];' +
              ' UPDATE [dbo].[' + @tableName + ']' +
              ' SET [GEOSTART] = geometry::STGeomFromText(''POINT ('' + [X1] + '' '' + [Y1] + '')'', 4326) WHERE X1<>'''' and Y1<>'''' '; 
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```